# Nested div vertical align problem

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, html

I am trying to vertically center one div (containing a search bar) inside another (a top banner). I was under the impression that to do so you did the following:

```
#banner {
height: 35px;
width: 100%;
}

#searchbar {
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -7.5px; /* half of the height */
}
```

This works fine until you add the `margin-top` at which point it is applied to the `#banner` as well.

Is there an alternative way to do this, or am I just doing it wrong?

[Here's a jsFiddle of my actual code.](http://jsfiddle.net/vkJ78/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `line-height` with the value being the same as height of parent div.

As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/vkJ78/24/

CSS:

```
#banner    {
    background-color: #770E17;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    }

#src    {
    width: 300px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 3px;
    }

#srcdiv {
    width: 308px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 35px;
}
```

**EDIT:** Per recommendation from NGLN, this will also fix horizontal centering, `#srcdiv` and `#src` having equal widths.

Comment: -1 This solution is NOT centered because #src is wider than #srcdiv!

Comment: Width effects vertical align?

Comment: No. The total width of #srcdiv = 308px because of the padding and border. Narrow your solution's window and see the input isn't centered. Also, your solution depends on `overflow: visible` of #srcdiv, but that is the default setting for most browsers though.

Comment: OP requested vertical centering.

Comment: Ok, agreed. But we answerers should try to understand the full question. Combine mine answer with yours (for line-heigt being a realy good solution), and I will delete my answer as well as the downvote. Or just widen @srcdiv ;)

Comment: Updated to your recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `overflow: hidden` to #banner. To clear the float, I guess.

Then, modify the negative margin to `margin-top: -11px` in #srcdiv (you have to sum the div height, the border, and the padding for the total height)

http://jsfiddle.net/vkJ78/1/

Answer (score 0):

Give `margin:0px` and `padding:0px` and remove margin-top

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

}
```